# Adding cache.clear() to global save in Django

Tags: django, caching, save

Hopefully somebody knows a simple way to do this.

Is it possible to run the cache.clear() function on every save to any model?

I know Django docs show you how to implement per model, and overhead isn't an issue. I would like to clear the cache each and every time a change is made.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways you could do this.

Firstly you could create a common abstract base class that inherits from models.Model and overrides `save` to do the cache clear, then make all your models inherit from that.

Another way might be to use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/) - the pre and post save signals have `sender` as an optional argument, if you don't specify a particular model it will fire for all models.

Comment: `from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.core.cache import cache

@receiver(post_save)
def clear_the_cache(**kwargs):
    cache.clear()`

Comment: I think cache.clear() will clear the whole cache instead of the relevant cache to the particular model and because of that my other useful cache will also get cleared.
Is there any solution for this? and I have also checked the cache versioning doc. but I don't get it that how can I know the keys of the cache if I have cached the particular  view.

Answer (score 2):

@Daniel Rosemen. Sorry as I don't have much reputation I couldn't remove my comment.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

It was as simple as:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.core.cache import cache

@receiver(post_save)
def clear_the_cache(**kwargs):
    cache.clear()
```

Comment: Hi Andy, I'm thinking about applying this to a django oscar site. I'm wondering how it worked out for you? Whether there are any negative implications that you could think of?